# Find the integer solutions for an equation with rational fraction whose degree depends on another integer variable

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, diophantine-equations

Determine all positive integers $a$ for which the equation
$$\left ( 1 + \frac {1} {x} \right ) \cdot \left ( 1 + \frac {1} {x+1} \right ) \cdots  \left ( 1 + \frac {1} {x+a} \right ) = a - x $$
has at least one integer solution $x$.

For each such integer $a$, determine the corresponding solutions.

Comment: How far have you gotten with it?

Comment: Is the LHS equal to

$$
\frac{x+a+1}{x}
$$?

Comment: Lol at the title...

Comment: I don't find any integer solutions.  Are you sure the formula is correct?

Comment: @saulspatz (a,x) = (7,4) is a solution

Comment: @kyary So it is.  I'll have to check my calculations again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terms of the product can be made into simple fractions as
$$1+\frac{1}{x+k}=\frac{x+k+1}{x+k},$$
from which it is clear that the numerator of each term cancels against the denominator of the next term, so
\begin{eqnarray*}
a-x&=&\left ( 1 + \frac {1} {x} \right ) \cdot \left ( 1 + \frac {1} {x+1} \right ) \cdots  \left ( 1 + \frac {1} {x+a} \right )\\
&=&\left (\frac {x+1} {x} \right ) \cdot \left ( \frac {x+2} {x+1} \right ) \cdots  \left ( \frac {x+a+1} {x+a} \right )\\
&=&\frac{x+a+1}{x}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Then clearing the denominator and rearranging shows that $x$ is a root of the quadratic
$$X^2+(1-a)X+(1+a)=0,$$
which has an integral root if and only if its discriminant is a perfect square, which is
$$\Delta=(1-a)^2-4(1+a)=a^2-6a-3=(a-3)^2-12.$$
Of course if $a$ is too large then $(a-3)^2-12$ cannot be a perfect square; if $a>9$ then
$$(a-3)^2>\Delta=(a-3)^2-12=a^2-6a-3>a^2-8a+16=(a-4)^2,$$
and so $a\leq9$. It is then a quick check to find that only $a=7$ works, corresponding to $x=2$ and $x=4$.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly the LHS of the equation simplifies to $\frac{x+a+1}{x}$. But note that, this also enforces that our solution (say $x'$) to the equation $$\frac{x+a+1}{x} = a- x$$ must satisfy $x'\neq0, x'\neq -1, \ldots, x' \neq -a$.

Now, the equation at hand is $x^2 + (1-a)x +a+1 = 0$, for which we need to find the positive integers $a$ such that the equation has at least one integer solution.

Considering the determinant of the equation, $D = (a-3)^2 - 12 \geq 0$, for the equation to have real solutions. Also, $a>0$. Thus, $a \in [3 + 2\sqrt3, \infty)$.

The solutions must be an integer, which will be true if the discriminant $D$ is a perfect square.

Hence, $(a-3)^2 - 12$ is a perfect square. We can change this to the following equation:
$$(a-3)^2 - 12 = b^2$$
for some integers $a,b$ where $a \in [3 + 2\sqrt3, \infty)$ and as $a$ is an integer, we have $a \in [7, \infty)$.

The above equation gives us $(a-3+b)(a-3-b) = 12$. Now, we can consider the pair of integers whose product gives us 12. Note that, both the integers should be odd, or both should be even.

This gives us the following pairs: (2, 6), (6, 2), (-2, -6), (-6, -2).

Solving for

1. $(2,6)$, we get $a=7, b =-2$
2. $(6,2)$, $a=7, b = 2$
3. $(-2,-6)$, $a =-1, b = 2$
4. $(-6, -2)$ , $ a = -1, b = -2$

Clearly, only the first two give us a valid pair as $a\in [7, \infty)$. Hence, $a=7$. Now, we check the solutions of the quadratic equation, which becomes
$$x^2 - 6x +8 = 0$$
The roots are $x' = 4$ and $x' = 2$, which also satisfy the enforced inequalities, which we stated in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

### HINT

The LHS can be rewritten as

$$\left ( 1 + \frac {1} {x} \right ) \cdot \left ( 1 + \frac {1} {x+1} \right ) \cdots  \left ( 1 + \frac {1} {x+a} \right ) = \frac{(x+1)\cdots(x+a+1)}{x(x+1)\cdots(x+a)} = \frac{x+a+1}{x}
$$

Hence, the problem reduces to
$$
\frac{x+a+1}{x} = a-x
$$
Since we are lookign for integer value of $a$ and $x$, the RHS is an integer. Thus, $\frac{x+a+1}{x}$ must also be an integer. Therefore, $x | a+1$.

Moving on, we have that
$$
x+a+1 = (a-x)x \iff x^2-(a-1)x+(a+1) = 0
$$

Can you continue from here?

P.S.: The real solutions are

$$x_1 = \frac{a-1 - \sqrt{a^2 -6a -3}}{2} \quad \text{and} \quad x_2 = \frac{a-1 +\sqrt{a^2 -6a -3}}{2} $$